# Ubuntu group file permissions on creation

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I am setting up a Wordpress site on an Ubuntu 14.04 server using Apache.  In this build I use Bamboo to deploy to this server.  I have a user named bamboo that is added to the group www-data and is not a sudo user. When I create new files as this user the chown on the files are `bamboo:bamboo` but I need it to be `bamboo:www-data`.  I can not for the life of me remember how I did this in the past.

File structure looks like this:

```
/var/www/website/release-1
```

I have run these commands:

```
usermod -aG www-data bamboo
adduser bamboo www-data
chown -R bamboo:www-data /var/www/website/
```

I can make this work using `chmod g+s -R /var/www/website/` but I do not want to use (setgid).  I am fairly certain I have done this before without using setgid.  I have tried nearly ever set of permissions I can think of to get this to work, what am I forgetting?

Comment: is bamboo a member of group www-data?  It sounds like you want the default group for bamboo to be www-data.

Comment: So I tried this last night and yes, this does fix this problem, although it creates another problem for me, it blows up my deployment script.  I get an ssh private key error.  If I can fix this error I might have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured out what was going wrong.  Posting this for people in the future, there are two ways to achieve this.

1. This method uses setgid, I do not want to use this method because it adds permissions that are not needed, you can look up when and when not to use this method, but it does work.

   `sudo chmod g+s -R /var/www/website/`
2. This method sets the default group for a user to www-data.  This now makes all files created by that user with permissions bamboo:www-data.

   `sudo usermod -g www-data bamboo`

But there is a gotcha in the second method. Note that if you run this command and you use a private key to login into your server. It might change the permissions of your `/home/bamboo/.ssh` folder and key.  So check your permissions on these. You want the following permissions.

```
bamboo:bamboo ~/.ssh
bamboo:bamboo ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```